# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Increasing Max Cells and Export to Excel

Tags: export, max, export-to-excel, business-intelligence, obiee

If possible, I want to increase the default configuration to enable OBIEE to display a combination of 60 facts and figures and <100k rows with export to excel

The following iconf,nqsconf and obijh changes enable the combination + export - however - environment is not "running stable" - crashes.

iconf

```
<Cube>
    <CubeMaxRecords>30000</CubeMaxRecords>
    <CubeMaxPopulatedCells>120000</CubeMaxPopulatedCells>
</Cube>

<Pivot>
        <MaxCells>3840000</MaxCells>
                <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>200000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
                <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>100000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
                <DisableAutoPreview>false</DisableAutoPreview>
            </Pivot>

 <Table>
        <MaxCells>3840000</MaxCells>
                <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>200000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDelivery>
                <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>100000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>
            </Table>

<ODBC>
            <ResultRowLimit>100000</ResultRowLimit>
        </ODBC>
```

obijh

Currently I am adding the following changes to the tests:

/OBIJH/config.xml: increase the socket time out and input stream limit, and set the read request before processing flag to false.

```
 <XMLP>
    <InputStreamLimitInKB>2097152</InputStreamLimitInKB>
    <ReadRequestBeforeProcessing>false</ReadRequestBeforeProcessing>
 </XMLP>
```

biconfig/bridgeconfig.properties: add the properties to increase the socket time out and the maximum number of connections in pool.

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Max that's a bit too vast a topic for one SO thread :) Come here: https://telegram.me/obihackers

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. We have current setting to display rows up to 300k rows, but whenever we tried to download the data above ~50 k in excel format it failed. It was working in csv format with no issue but in some cases it was also failing as well.

We tried InputStreamLimitInKB parameters in 1024kb increments up to GBs but never succeed. We also tweaked the socket time out and the maximum number of connections in pool in bridgeconfig.properties.

At last we removed the InputStreamLimitInKB by setting it to 0. As per oracle it should be done only in testing. But after doing this, it worked every time. Only concern here was with the CPU utilization as it was taking 10% of CPU power per thread.

We observed that up to certain limit JAVA host handled the memory allocation but beyond that it was killing the thread after sockettimeout.

So we learned that-

1. There is some bug which is not letting java to complete the export if InputStreamLimitInKB is set very high
2. With no limit in InputStreamLimitInKB, it is working well before sockettimeout.
3. Even with no limit environment is stable and export is working as expected.

FINALLY:
Please give it a try and log the memory and CPU usage over time. If you find something fishy, revert back to recommended parameter values.